# I'm build a webscraper for security news but links are duplicated

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm building a web-scraper to scrape multiple websites so I don't have to directly visit the website.

Currently I'm having problems with duplicated URLs, the script does what I want, but links are being duplicated and I don't want that.

Here's My code:

```
def HackerNews():
hackerNews = ['https://www.darkreading.com/attacks-breaches.asp','https://www.darkreading.com/application-security.asp',
           'https://www.darkreading.com/vulnerabilities-threats.asp', 'https://www.darkreading.com/endpoint-security.asp',
           'https://www.darkreading.com/IoT.asp','https://www.darkreading.com/vulnerabilities-threats.asp'
           ]
keywords = ["bitcoin", "bit", "BTC", "Bit", "Security","Attack", "Breach","Cyber",
"Ransomware","Botnet","Worm","Hacked","Hack","Hackers","Flaw", "Risk","Danger" ]

for link in hackerNews:
   request = urllib2.Request(link)
   request.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla 5.0')
   websitecontent = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
   soup = BeautifulSoup(websitecontent, 'html.parser')

   headers = soup.findAll('header', {'class' : 'strong medium'})

   for h in headers:
       a = h.find("a")

       for keyword in keywords:
           if keyword in a["title"]:
               print("Title: " + a["title"] + " \nLink: " "https://darkreading.com" + a["href"])

HackerNews()
```

Here's an Example of the output:

Title: Android Ransomware Kits on the Rise in the Dark Web
Link: https://darkreading.com/mobile/android-ransomware-kits-on-the-rise-in-the-dark-web-/d/d-id/1330591

Title: Bitcoin Miner NiceHash Hacked, Possibly Losing $62 Million in Bitcoin
Link: https://darkreading.com/cloud/bitcoin-miner-nicehash-hacked-possibly-losing-$62-million-in-bitcoin/d/d-id/1330585

Title: Bitcoin Miner NiceHash Hacked, Possibly Losing $62 Million in Bitcoin 
Link: https://darkreading.com/cloud/bitcoin-miner-nicehash-hacked-possibly-losing-$62-million-in-bitcoin/d/d-id/1330585

Title: Bitcoin Miner NiceHash Hacked, Possibly Losing $62 Million in Bitcoin 
Link: https://darkreading.com/cloud/bitcoin-miner-nicehash-hacked-possibly-losing-$62-million-in-bitcoin/d/d-id/1330585

Title: Uber Used $100K Bug Bounty to Pay, Silence Florida Hacker: Report 
Link: https://darkreading.com/attacks-breaches/uber-used-$100k-bug-bounty-to-pay-silence-florida-hacker-report/d/d-id/1330584

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, instead of printing it directly, you can make a dictionary with all the links. Or if you want to keep it in order a list of tupils.
Before appending, you can check if it is already in the list.

```
def HackerNews():
hackerNews = ['https://www.darkreading.com/attacks-breaches.asp','https://www.darkreading.com/application-security.asp',
           'https://www.darkreading.com/vulnerabilities-threats.asp', 'https://www.darkreading.com/endpoint-security.asp',
           'https://www.darkreading.com/IoT.asp','https://www.darkreading.com/vulnerabilities-threats.asp'
           ]
keywords = ["bitcoin", "bit", "BTC", "Bit", "Security","Attack", "Breach","Cyber",
"Ransomware","Botnet","Worm","Hacked","Hack","Hackers","Flaw", "Risk","Danger" ]

output = []

for link in hackerNews:
   request = urllib2.Request(link)
   request.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla 5.0')
   websitecontent = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
   soup = BeautifulSoup(websitecontent, 'html.parser')

   headers = soup.findAll('header', {'class' : 'strong medium'})

   for h in headers:
       a = h.find("a")

       for keyword in keywords:
           if keyword in a["title"]:
               if (a["title"], a["href"]) not in output:
                   output.append((a["title"], a["href"]))

   for link in output:        
       print("Title: " + link[0] + " \nLink: " "https://darkreading.com" + link[1])

HackerNews()
```

Did not fix your indentation problem, also didnt test it. But it should convey my point :)

---

edit: worked for python 3 with:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def HackerNews():
    hackerNews = ['https://www.darkreading.com/attacks-breaches.asp','https://www.darkreading.com/application-security.asp',
               'https://www.darkreading.com/vulnerabilities-threats.asp', 'https://www.darkreading.com/endpoint-security.asp',
               'https://www.darkreading.com/IoT.asp','https://www.darkreading.com/vulnerabilities-threats.asp'
               ]
    keywords = ["bitcoin", "bit", "BTC", "Bit", "Security","Attack", "Breach","Cyber",
    "Ransomware","Botnet","Worm","Hacked","Hack","Hackers","Flaw", "Risk","Danger" ]

    output = []

    for link in hackerNews:
       request = Request(link)
       request.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla 5.0')
       websitecontent = urlopen(request).read()
       soup = BeautifulSoup(websitecontent, 'html.parser')

       headers = soup.findAll('header', {'class' : 'strong medium'})

       for h in headers:
           a = h.find("a")

           for keyword in keywords:
               if keyword in a["title"]:
                   if (a["title"], a["href"]) not in output:
                       output.append((a["title"], a["href"]))

       for link in output:
           print("Title: " + link[0] + " \nLink: " "https://darkreading.com" + link[1])

HackerNews()
```

Comment: this works, but i think the problem is that some websites have the same articles in different categories

Comment: Well, then you can sort out by just the name or just by the link. You could even compare the articles and throw out accordingly, but that might be a bit overkill ^^